# How to increase random.randrange from maybe (10,20) to (12,24)

Tags: python, random

I'm trying to increase the value of the ranges in my code
for example: `random.randrange(0,10)` becoming `random.randrange(10,20)`
I've tried to solve the problem but I'm not sure why it doesn't work

---

Here is the code

```
da = 0
da2 = 10
e1 = random.randrange(da,da2)

a1 = int(input("how much would you like to increase strength?"))
a1 + da
a1 + da2
    
print (e1)
```

Then it comes out as:

```
how much would you like to increase strength?20
8
```

Everytime I try to make `e1` change it only prints out numbers from 0-10 and not 10-20

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: You will be better off showing us two snippets of running code. The first with the original settings and the second with the alternate settings and asking how to change between the two.

Comment: I want to know how I can increase a random range by perhaps 10 in my program since I want my program to be able to upgrade the damage of the character without the damage always being always 100 so I want to know if its possible to increase the range in random.randrange if lets say they want increase how much damage they can deal to the enemy.

Comment: @quamrana 
This is what I've tried to do to increase the range
e1 = random.randrange(10,20)
a1 = int(input("how much would you like to increase strength?"))

print ("Your se1 + a1)

but it only adds it up of course                                                                                    how much would you like to increase strength?10                                                                  20 (I'm trying to increase the range not stat

Comment: I can't make any sense from your comment. As I said previously: "You will be better off showing us two snippets of running code. The first with the original settings and the second with the alternate settings and asking how to change between the two."

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by settings, sorry.

Comment: Ok, I meant the parameters to `randint()`. I'm guessing you want to change them somehow. Do you mean that at one point in time you want to execute: `e1 = random.randrange(10,20)`, and then at a different point in time you want: `e1 = random.randrange(12,24)`?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant, thank you

Comment: Ok, well now you know how to update your question with some code that asks what you mean.

Comment: Now that you've edited the question, we can see that you read in `a1` and add it to your `da`'s, but neither assign the results nor generate a new `e1`.

Comment: @pjs How would I assign the results or generate a new e1, thank you.

Comment: [Assignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_(computer_science)) is a fundamental operation in imperative languages such as python.  You should go back and review chapter 1 of whatever textbook or tutorial you're using.  Note that when you `print(e1)` you're printing the last value assigned to that variable, so of course it will be a result contained within the original range.

Comment: Ah yes, thank you. 
I’ve corrected it as

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to increase the upper and lower limits, you need to reassign to the variables that hold the limits:

```
da = 0
da2 = 10
e1 = random.randrange(da, da2)
print('Sample from original range:', e1)

a1 = int(input("how much would you like to increase strength?"))
da += a1
da2 += a1
    
e1 = random.randrange(da, da2)
print('Sample from new range:', e1)
```